# « Jusqu'au franco de port » : différences avec « port payé », « franc de port » ; fréquence ; susbstantivation ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, lexique, emprunts, locutions, italien

> Là encore Amazon est dans la viseur dans la mesure où le géant
>   américain (et la grande distribution) bénéficie de la part des
>   distributeurs « d'avantages commerciaux qui peuvent aller jusqu'au
>   franco de port ». ([Lapresse.ca](https://www.lapresse.ca/arts/litterature/201906/25/01-5231593-les-libraires-defendent-le-prix-unique-du-livre-contre-amazon.php))

[*Franco de port*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/franco_de_port), c'est une locution adverbiale signifiant que le port est payé par l'expéditeur, comme [*franc de port*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/franc_de_port) (qui peut aussi être adjectif) ou [*port payé*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/port_pay%C3%A9). C'est un emprunt à l'italien (l'abréviation de *franco porto*) d'un emprunt au français (*franc* ; [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/franco)) ; *franc de port* (1723), *franco* (1754).

- Peut-on identifier des nuances dans l'emploi de l'un ou l'autre ?
- Peut-on étayer les fréquences d'emploi des locutions ? *Franco de
  port* concurrence-t-elle ou supplante-t-elle les autres ; quel serait
  l'intérêt de cette locution (elle est plus longue d'un caractère et
  morphologiquement identique à *franc de port*) ?
- Est-il juste dans l'exemple de faire précéder la locution d'un
  déterminant (*à le, au*), était-il plus juste d'employer la préposition
  à ou devait-on reformuler autrement et si oui comment (quel substantif utiliser ici) ?

Answer (score 1):

Bizarrement, c'est l'expression "franco de port" qui l'a emporté sur les autres expressions. Je n'en connais pas la raison.

Pour ce qui est du déterminant, la phrase demande une graduation des frais de port importants au début et qui diminuent par palier. Du coup, le dernier palier est le *(palier du)* franco de port, parce que "palier de" requiert un nom derrière.

Comment: Intéressant, le _palier_ est une grande extrapolation, on a _avantages commerciaux_ juste avant... _Tarif_ serait redondant, _transport_ ou _expédition_ demanderaient possiblement _en_. Je ne suis pas convaincu. Dans mon coin du monde, l'expression sera sans doute peu connue, personnellement c'est la première fois que je la rencontrais, et je ne suis pas né de la dernière pluie et on a toujours eu une communauté italienne assez vivante ici. Une découverte.